# Footer Layout and Vertical Dividers

Tags: html, css

Just want to ask a few questions about this example:

[image]

What is the best way to do this 3 column layout these days? Of course there were tables and now there are divs etc etc. What the **latest** greatest way to accomplish this? If it was totally up to me I'd have a container div, containing 3 other ones. Set to `width: 33%;` and `display: inline;`

Also, how does one get those vertical dividers? Again as far as I know you use that in a table and only display certain borders by which you get a vertical rule effect.

But what's the best way these days to get this effect? Having html5 and css3 in your toolbox..

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what do you mean by "horizontal dividers"? only see the vertical ones.

Comment: @RainDiao - Ah man! I meant vertical, sorry I'll change it quick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

**HTML**

```
<div class="outer">
<div class="wrap">
<div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum</div>
<div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum </div>
<div class="sub">Lorem Ipsum </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.outer {
    background: #734e91;
    padding: 12px;
}
.wrap {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.sub {
    padding: 12px;
    width: 32%;
    height: 150px;
    background: #734e91;
    display: table-cell;
    border-right: solid #a175c4 1px;  
}
.sub:last-child {
    border: 0px;
}
```

[**DEMO UPDATED**](http://jsfiddle.net/BjbH2/3/)

Comment: Ah nice, yes that's better. Thank you :)

Comment: @DeanGrobler Welcm. You can remove the .wrap div also. http://jsfiddle.net/BjbH2/4/

Comment: Besides some CSS mistakes (omitting semicolons), this solutions is not really bullet-prove. The `.sub`-items will have unpredictable widths (32% width + 2x 12px padding + 1px border).

Comment: @kleinfreund omitting semicolons?? where?

Comment: @Sowmya I already added them trough edit. (They're still in your demo)

Comment: @kleinfreund FYI - semicolons are requires only when you continue to write the next rule of css otherwise its not a problem if you miss out the last semicolons

Comment: @Sowmya According to the CSS3 specification: "Each declaration has a property name, followed by a colon and the property value, and finished with a semicolon." (source: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css3-syntax/#syntax-description) And besides that its just good coding style to use them properly.

Comment: @kleinfreund Check here http://dustinbrewer.com/your-last-css-attribute-doesnt-need-a-semicolon/ and http://www.cssnewbie.com/15-surefire-ways-to-break-your-css/ This is also well known for optimizing the css

Comment: @Sowmya The first article is from 2007 – really? And the second one already points out what fatal errors this may produce. It's bad coding practice.

Answer (score 4):

**jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/yDXLp/3/**

```
<style>
    footer {
        background-color: #eee;
        margin: 10px auto;

    }
    footer h2 {
        font-size: 1.5em;
        font-weight: bold;
    }
    footer > div,
    footer > .divider {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: middle;   
    }
    footer > div {
        padding: 1%;
        text-align: center;
        width:30%;
    }

    footer > .divider {
        font-style: normal;
        height: 240px;
        border: 1px solid #888;
        -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #ccc;
        box-shadow: 1px 2px 1px #ccc;
    }
</style>

<footer>
    <div>
        <h2>Our Client</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </p>
        <button>Read more</button>
    </div>
    <i class="divider"></i>

    <div>
        <h2>Pay Rates</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum  </p>
        <button>Read more</button>
    </div>
    <i class="divider"></i>
    <div>
        <h2>About US</h2>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum Lorem Ipsum </p>
        <button>Read more</button>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using `box-sizing: border-box;` (an alternative way to the standard css box model).

**What does `box-sizing: border-box;` do?** If you define the width of a div (e.g. 33%) and add borders and paddings it longer affects the calculated with of your div. It remains 33% of the parent with (33% - (borders + paddings)).

The standard box model adds them to the calculated with of 33% (33% + borders + paddings in our case).

**HTML markup:**

```
<div class="footer">
    <div class="footer-item item1"></div>
    <div class="footer-item item2"></div>
    <div class="footer-item item3"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.footer {
    box-sizing: border-box; /* will need vendor prefixes for webkit and mozilla */
}

.footer-item {
    width: 33%;
    float: left;
}

.footer-item + .footer-item {
    border-left: 1px solid black;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Checkout Twitter Bootstrap(http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/), Gumby Framework(http://gumbyframework.com/)

These frameworks may provide you readymade functionality for the horizontal bar. Else use borders. Set all borders except right as transparent in color

Comment: Thank you, although I do already know about those frameworks. I want to know how you get the effect with pure html and css. Thanks though!

Comment: These frameworks as you must be knowing are based on pure html and css . You can edit their html and css very easily for the effects you desire. Also have you tried out the Less Css framework? If not check it out, It may answer your query: http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 1):

The css3 way of doing columns is using ["column-*" family of properties](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_columns.asp)

They are now supported by all major browsers and there should be no problems with them.

Personally I use these styles in my [home site](http://asm32.hopto.org) and they provide pretty flexible (perhaps with some small shortcomings) layout formatting.

Comment: @KhurramIshaque: The question was about latest technologies. What IE has to do here? :P

Comment: because the site contents using css3 columns will not show for IE users.

Answer (score 1):

The best way depends on what you want to achieve. How should the columns behave to resizing of the window etc.

If I was doing something like in the picture I would probably use a fixed width so I could have control of the line width for the text.

By using inline-block you can achieve columns that are collapsed and put under each other on a smaller screen (like a phone)

Try to figure aout the desired behavior first.

**EDIT:** Oops, I misread and confused horizontal with vertical ;-) I think the other answers explains his enough though.

Correct me if I'm wrong but I think that the css3 column property is for multiple columns for the same text body.

Comment: Thank you for elaborating on the answer. It's true that it does depend what functionality you want. Also, yes the column property is, as you say, used to make columns of the same text body. So probably not the best option in this case.